# How to do I use Excel to make three cells change when any of the others are changed?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a table that can calculate the cost per week, per month and per year of any value.

If the per week value is entered it needs to calculate the per month and per year value.

If the per month value is entered, it needs to calculate the per week and per year value.

If the per year value is entered, it needs to calculate the per week and per month value.

I can only use three cells.

I haven't a clue how to do this. I don't even know how to run the code in Excel. I heard you have to use VBA but I have never touched Visual Basic let alone, used in in Excel.

Please can some one help. This is very important to me. Thanks in advance for any help :)

[image: This is the space I need to use]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with a more formula driven route, I would suggest using an input range and a result range. In the attached screenshot, the blue cells are for inputs while the below formulas go i the row below the inputs.

For days

```
= if(not(isblank(A8)),A8,if(not(isblank(B8)),B8/30,C8/365))
```

For months

```
=if(not(isblank(A8)),A8*30,if(not(isblank(B8)),B8,C8/12))
```

For years

```
=if(not(isblank(A8)),A8*365,if(not(isblank(B8)),B8*12,C8))
```

Note1: I assumed 30 days a month and 365 days in a year. 
Note 2: The order the formula calculates is first days, then months, then years. So, if something is in days it will need to be cleared out when inputting months and so on.

[image]